# Pascal triangle using a function

Tags: c, function, loops, logic, pascals-triangle

> well I've got it how to construct the pascal triangle and the code
>   below is flawless but...in this code i am making the 1 to appear in
>   first row by creating a new for loop especially for it... is there a
>   way to generate pascal triangle without using an exclusive for loop
>   for the 1 to appear in first... any help is much appreciated :)

```
//pascal triangle with ncr function
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <conio.h>
        int ncr(int i,int j);
        int main()
        {
            int i,j,v,n,f,s;
            printf("Enter the number of rows required\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            f=n;
     //this is what i am exclusively using for printing 1 in 1st row
            for(;f>0;f--)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("1\n");
     //is there a way to generate the above 1 using only the below for loop
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(s=n-i;s>0;s--)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    v=ncr(i,j);
                    printf("%d ",v);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        int ncr(int i,int j)
        {
            int k;
            float ans=1;
            for(;j>=1;j--)
                {
                    ans=((ans*i)/j);
                    i--;
                }
                k=ans;
                return(k);
        }
```

Comment: Why does it look like your implementation of `ncr` is _inside_ the `main` method?

Comment: ah! i get it... you're right i've implemented it inside the main function... thanks @Arc676

Comment: and `int ncr(int i,int j);
    {` remove `;`

Comment: ya checked... i got how to construct it perfectly but i'm using an exclusive loop to generate 1 in the first row... is there a way to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, you'll notice that the `ncr` function is defined *inside* the `main` method. Move the implementation of `ncr` outside of `main`.

Also, noticed by @BLUEPIXY, your implementation of `ncr` has an excess `;`:

```
int ncr(int i,int j); //<<right here
{
//...
```

**EDIT** Solution to second problem (see [Pascal's Triangle on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle))

The "first" row of the triangle is actually the zeroth row. Your outer loop starts with `i = 1` and therefore the "first" row contains `1C0` and `1C1`. The "first" or zeroth row should actually contain only `0C0`. New loop:

```
//notice how the i here has changed to 0
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(s=n-i;s>0;s--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        v=ncr(i,j);
        printf("%d ",v);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: and as you said earlier, should the ncr function be defined before main function?

Comment: That is one option. However, as noticed by @Mukit Chowdhury, you already have a prototype above your `main` method so it's alright to put it after. @Mukit why didn't you post an answer if you saw the mistake?

Comment: i've made the changes... and no errors are shown but, there is no output... is there any logical error?

Comment: Actually, just by copying your code (and removing `conio.h` because I'm on Mac) I get infinite `1`s printed

Comment: got it man! i need to mention j++ and j=0 not 1... in 8th line of main function if not it will embark on a journey to infinity and beyond :)... but this'll make 2 1's print on the first line

Comment: @ch3rub7 I noticed you un-accepted my answer. Is something not working?

Comment: No...the function thing is settled but here... I'm not able to print the 1 in the first row by using the loop I'm creating one more loop for it... So I wanted to know a program which constructs the whole program without me manually putting up a 1 on top... Is such kind of changing a question is not accepted?

Comment: Not sure. I'll look into it

Comment: I found the solution. Also, since factorials get big very quickly, use `double` if you need to support large values because it can hold bigger numbers.